# Right inheritance order

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

We need to have instances of light/heavy cars and instances of arctic light/heavy cars. What is the correct way of inheritance (or composition?) not to duplicate code of ArcticCar code into ArcticLight/HeavyCar?

```
class Car {
    startEnging() {
        turnOnPeripheralDevices();
        checkFuelLevel();
        // + other default actions. Some of them can be overrided in child classes to add specific actions
        log("engine started");
    }
    /* Common car stuff */
}

class LightCar extend Car {
    override startEngine() {
        log("light car prepare to start");
        parent.startEnging();
    }
    /* Basic light car stuff */
}
class HeavyCar extend Car {
    override startEngine() {
        turnOnLights();
        log("heavy car prepare to start");
        parent.startEnging();
    }
    override turnOnPeripheralDevices() {
        parent.turnOnPeripheralDevices(); //Car's default actions
        // additional actions for HeavyCars only
    }
    /* Basic heavy car stuff */
}

class ArcticCar extend Car {
    override startEngine() {
        warmUpEngine()
        wait10seconds();
        log("arctic mode: warming up engine");
        parent.startEnging();
    }
    /* A lot of common stuff for arctic cars. Can overwrite some common Car's functions */
}

class LightArcticCar extend **LightCar, ArcticCar** {
    override startEngine() {
        log("arctic ligh car prepare to start");
        parent.startEnging();
    }
    /* Arctic light car stuff. Can overwrite some specific LightCar's functions */
}
class HeavyArcticCar extend **HeavyCar, ArcticCar** {
    override startEngine() {
        if(checkForecast())
            parent.startEnging();
    }
    override turnOnPeripheralDevices() {
        parent.turnOnPeripheralDevices(); //Car's + HeavyCar's default actions
        // additional actions of HeavyArctic car
    }
    /* Arctic heavy car stuff. Can overwrite some specific HeavyCar's functions */
}

class Main {
    buggy = new LightCar();
    awdSUV = new HeavyCar();

    snowmobile = new ArcticLightCar();
    mobileLaboratory = new ArcticHeavyCar();
}
```

Comment: favor Composition over Inheritance

Comment: Might be a good spot for the Decorator Pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: Unless you explicitly say so in `HeavyArcticCar`, how would you know whether to turn on the lights before or after warming up the engine?

Comment: @lhoworko for the decorator pattern : HeavyArcticCar has to implement all public methods of Car, HeavyCar and ArcticCar classes even if I overwrite only one parent's method.

Comment: @sidgate : any exmple for the above code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Andreas : need to warm up engine for 10 seconds and call parent's engineStart method witch will turn on the lights.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: @Maxx Didn't you try with Java8 default methods in interfaces??

Comment: @jaco0646: `HeavyAcrticCar` should extend `AcrticCar` and `HeavyCar` classes same time :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to approach this design is to take closer look at the problem domain. To me, it looks like you have more then one entity (Car) there. There is Engine, CarLights, Forecast and maybe others. 
If that is the case, a better design would be to have classes for each entity in your model:

```
class Car {
   protected Engine engine;
   protected CarLights carLights;
   void start() {
      engine.start();
   }
}

class Engine {
    void start() { ... }
    void warmUp() { ... } 
}

class CarLights {
   void turnOn() { ... }
}

class Forecast {
   void check() { ... }
}
```

The hierarchy would be then:

```
class LightCar extend Car {
    // no code for start

    /* Basic light car stuff */
}

class HeavyCar extend Car{

    void start() {
        carLights.turnOn();
        log("heavy car prepare to start");
        parent.start();
    }

    /* Basic heavy car stuff */
}

class ArcticCar extend   Car {
    void startEngine() {
        engine.warmUp()
        wait10seconds();
        log("arctic mode: warming up engine");
        parent.start();
    }
    /* A lot of common stuff for arctic cars. 
       Can overwrite some common Car's functions */
}

class HeavyArcticCar extend ArcticCar {
    Forecast f; // if it a component of a car. If not, then it should be a local variable in start()
    void start() {

        if( f.check())
            parent.startEnging();
    }
}
```

One of the strong points of OOP is that it allows you to model a solution in code that will closely the problem at hand.

For example, composition in this case is much more natural, it will reflect closely the real components of the car.

Plus, there is this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

So the responsibilities here are:

Engine - code to warm up and start

CarLights - code to turn on/off lights

Forecast - code to check

Car and derivatives - put all 3 above together and use their capabilities.

On a final note, the design can be further improved by making Engine, CarLights and Forecast implement a common interface (like CarComponent), because they have this in common, they are all car components, and using a list of CarComponent in the Car class. This would be even more flexible, since you can add or remove components more easily.

Comment: Same problem: HeavyArcticCar.start() won't turn the lights on (default behavior of all Heavy cars).
Besides turnLightOn() there are some other default actions for all Heavy cars. And there are HeavySandCar -> SandCar and other car classes and groups :(

Comment: You can because you explicitly call the turnOn method on the carLights instance in HeavyArcticCar.start() method.
On the other hand, if you want to handle multiple categories and also have 100% code reuse using just inheritance (or right inheritance order, as you say in your question), the answer is simple: you can't, in a language with single inheritance. Even in a language with multiple inheritance, you will get a messy design.

Comment: I've updated topic's code, probably will be easier to see the problem :)
HeavyArcticCar is a HeavyCar and ArcticCar in the same time :( ArcticCar is a Car and HeavyCar is a Car.

Comment: so I had to duplicate HeavyCar's or ArcticCar's code to HeavyAcrcticCar, HeavySandCar and others Heavy*Cars.

Comment: thank you! I've re-read yesterday some patterns and articles.. And didnt found anything matching 100% for this case :(